# MySQL UPDATE multiple columns

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to put several variables that are parsed through ZeroMQ into MySQL through Python.

I'm able to print these variables already by doing:

```
for i in json_msg["PropertyInfoMsg"]:
        print i.["PropertyType"] + ": " + i["PropertyValue"]
```

Putting it into the MySQL I was thinking of doing something along the lines of:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="user", passwd="pass", db="database")
cursor = db.cursor()
for i in json_msg["PropertyInfoMsg"]:
    cursor.execute("""UPDATE settings SET value=%s WHERE name=%s""" % (i.["PropertyType"], i["PropertyValue"]))
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

Although I'm thinking there might be a better way to do this? Perhaps getting a single string to update everything in one go?

Comment: just how many fields are going to be updated? a couple wouldn't be a huge issue, but if you're doing 40 or 50 fields, that's 40 or 50 individual updates with 40-50 individual index updates - highly inefficient.

Comment: @MarcB And how would you do it? Maybe create a temporal table with `[type, value]` ?

Comment: build one single `update ... set field1=val1, field2=val2, etc...` query.

Comment: @MarcB In that case doesnt work, you need different `where` for diferent `sets`.

Comment: ah. I see. it's a key=value table? then yeah. you'll be stuck with individual update queries.